# Can anyone spot the missing curly bracket

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, curly-braces

I am at my wits end. I have been tinkering with my code for like 3 hours now trying to sort out this missing curly bracket. Everytime I think I've fixed it it comes up with a new missing curly bracket on a different line. Please help me I want to cry.

Code is as follows:

```
 function addCTHValue() {

    $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/nh71g")  
    .done(function(data) {
    });

        function processCTHValueData(data) {

            var min = Infinity; 
            var max = -Infinity; 


            for (var feature in data.features) {
                var properties = data.features[feature].properties;

            for (var attribute in properties) {
                  if ( attribute = 'CTH Value' )

                  {
                      if (properties[attribute] < min) {
                          min = properties[attribute]; 
                      }
                      if (properties[attribute] > max) {
                          max = properties[attribute]; 
                      }
                  }
            }}  

          return { 
              min : min,
              max : max
        }}


    function CTHValueSymbols(data) {


        CTHValueCountries = L.geoJson(data, {


            pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
                return L.circleMarker(latlng, { 
                    fillColor: "#501e65",  
                    weight: 2,            
                    fillOpacity: 0.5,      
                    radius: feature.properties["CTH Value"]/100
                })}
                .on({

                        mouseover: function(e) {
                            this.openPopup();
                            this.setStyle({fillColor: 'green'});  
                        },
                        mouseout: function(e) {
                            this.closePopup();
                            this.setStyle({fillColor: '#501e65'});
                        }
                });
        }
        }).addTo(map);

    function calcCTHValueRadius(attributeValue) {

        var scaleFactor = 0.01;
        var area = attributeValue * scaleFactor;

        return Math.sqrt(area/Math.PI);
        }

        $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/nh71g").done(function(data) {

        var info = processCTHValueData(data);
        CTHValueSymbols(data)
            });
    }
```

allegedly the missing curly bracket is on the following line: CTHValueCountries = L.geoJson(data, { but tbh I think my brain has blocked out the sight of curly brackets at this point. Please help?

Comment: The `.done()` function is being closed instant? `.done(function(data) {
    });`

Comment: `processCTHValueData` is only defined within `addCTHValue()` and you attempt to call it later. I think there's a fundamental lack of understanding about scopes and what the brackets are for

Comment: `if ( attribute = 'CTH Value' )` should be `if ( attribute == 'CTH Value' )` ( or `===` if you want strict equality)

Comment: there's no need to be rude Joel M I'm a complete beginner to Javascript and I was trying to follow a tutorial

Comment: lol I'm sorry, I figured someone else wrote it. I wasn't trying to be rude.

Answer (score 0):

**Pairs of curly braces denote new scopes**, or an object literal since this is JavaScript.

Look at this code:

```
 function addCTHValue() {

    $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/nh71g")  
    .done(function(data) {
    });

        function processCTHValueData(data) {

            var min = Infinity; 
            var max = -Infinity; 


            for (var feature in data.features) {
                var properties = data.features[feature].properties;

            for (var attribute in properties) {
                  if ( attribute = 'CTH Value' )

                  {
                      if (properties[attribute] < min) {
                          min = properties[attribute]; 
                      }
                      if (properties[attribute] > max) {
                          max = properties[attribute]; 
                      }
                  }
            }}  

          return { 
              min : min,
              max : max
        }}
```

Can you tell what lines of code are executed when `addCTHValue()` is run? What lines *should* be executed? If you can answer that question, placing curly brackets becomes insanely easy. This code is a bit of a mess, so I can only attempt to answer that question.

Every line of code between a pair of curly braces (that is, inside a code block or object literal) should be one indentation level further than the surrounding code. Also, it's rather bad style to ever write two curly braces on one line, so don't do that especially if you don't understand their purpose. Let's rewrite the above code with those things in mind:

```
 function addCTHValue() {

    $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/nh71g")  
    .done(function(data) {
    });

    function processCTHValueData(data) {

       var min = Infinity; 
       var max = -Infinity; 


       for (var feature in data.features) {
          var properties = data.features[feature].properties;

          for (var attribute in properties) {
             if ( attribute = 'CTH Value' ) {
                if (properties[attribute] < min) {
                   min = properties[attribute]; 
                }
                if (properties[attribute] > max) {
                   max = properties[attribute]; 
                }
             }
          }
       }  

       return { 
          min : min,
          max : max
       }
    }
```

Notice: In this code block, going straight down from `function addCTHValue()` you **do not reach a curly brace**. Where does the function end? Clearly `processCTHValueData(data)` is actually contained within `addCTHValue()` right now - is it supposed to be?? If you can answer these questions, placing the curly braces is a very simple task, but if you can't, we can't either (and thus can't fix your code for you).

Comment: I don't know if processCTHValueData(data) is supposed to go inside addCTHValue(). I assumed it was. I'm trying to follow this tutorial: https://neiugis.github.io/lab7/ but I'm just really struggling. Even after copying some else's solution, I am still getting an error message which says I am missing a curly bracket.

Comment: @sophhGIS Looking at that tutorial, I can see which sections are directly copied, but somehow your copying is incomplete... like `function CTHValueSymbols()` was copied without the last line and curly bracket for some reason and I don't even see `$.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/nh71g")` as being in any function at all. I think you're going to need to follow a basic javascript tutorial and try to really understand what the code is doing before attempting to simply copy each code block in sequence and have it work.

Comment: I haven't copied all of it because I don't want to to use the time slider. I couldn't find a basic proportional circles map that doesn't use a plugin to create the map.

Answer (score 0):

as @joel-m said, the code is a mess and looks like you didn't even tested it before, as far as I see there are a lot of errors, but looks like you go putting `{}` everyway.

the `addTo(map)` was outside of the call of the `GeoJS` call. now this should work

```
function addCTHValue() {
  $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/nh71g').done(function(data) {});

  function processCTHValueData(data) {
    var min = Infinity;
    var max = -Infinity;

    for (var feature in data.features) {
      var properties = data.features[feature].properties;

      for (var attribute in properties) {
        if ((attribute = 'CTH Value')) {
          if (properties[attribute] < min) {
            min = properties[attribute];
          }
          if (properties[attribute] > max) {
            max = properties[attribute];
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return {
      min: min,
      max: max
    };
  }

  function CTHValueSymbols(data) {
    CTHValueCountries = L.geoJson(data, {
      pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
          fillColor: '#501e65',
          weight: 2,
          fillOpacity: 0.5,
          radius: feature.properties['CTH Value'] / 100
        });
      }.on({
        mouseover: function(e) {
          this.openPopup();
          this.setStyle({ fillColor: 'green' });
        },
        mouseout: function(e) {
          this.closePopup();
          this.setStyle({ fillColor: '#501e65' });
        }
      })
    }).addTo(map);
  }  

  function calcCTHValueRadius(attributeValue) {
    var scaleFactor = 0.01;
    var area = attributeValue * scaleFactor;

    return Math.sqrt(area / Math.PI);
  }

  $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/nh71g').done(function(data) {
    var info = processCTHValueData(data);
    CTHValueSymbols(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help

I am super new to Javascript, I was following a tutorial but I guess I did it badly.
How do I test the code? I don't really understand how to communicate with the web console so maybe that's why I'm struggling.

Comment: i just got a new error: "(intermediate value).on is not a function", do you know what this means?

Answer (score -1):

```
function addCTHValue() {

$.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/nh71g")
    .done(function(data) {});

function processCTHValueData(data) {

    var min = Infinity;
    var max = -Infinity;


    for (var feature in data.features) {
        var properties = data.features[feature].properties;

        for (var attribute in properties) {
            if (attribute = 'CTH Value')

            {
                if (properties[attribute] < min) {
                    min = properties[attribute];
                }
                if (properties[attribute] > max) {
                    max = properties[attribute];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return {
        min: min,
        max: max
    }
}


function CTHValueSymbols(data) {
    CTHValueCountries = L.geoJson(data, {
            pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
                            return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                                fillColor: "#501e65",
                                weight: 2,
                                fillOpacity: 0.5,
                                radius: feature.properties["CTH Value"] / 100
                            })
                            .on({
                              mouseover: function(e) {
                                  this.openPopup();
                                  this.setStyle({fillColor: 'green'});  
                              },
                              mouseout: function(e) {
                                  this.closePopup();
                                  this.setStyle({fillColor: '#501e65'});
                              }
                            })
                        }
    }).addTo(map);
}

function calcCTHValueRadius(attributeValue) {

    var scaleFactor = 0.01;
    var area = attributeValue * scaleFactor;

    return Math.sqrt(area / Math.PI);
}

$.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/nh71g").done(function(data) {

    var info = processCTHValueData(data);
    CTHValueSymbols(data)
});}
```